# T-SQL- Single query to evaluate 2 different conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, compare, max

I have 2 columns TeamKey and Counter in my table.

What I need to do is, when there are different TeamKey values, I need to select the one which has the max Counter value. The other thing that I need to do is, when all the counter values are the same, I need to select the team key with the max value.

So far, I have been able to achieve part 1 where I select the teamKey with the max counter value using a ROW_NUMBER function (as well as an inner join), but I am drawing a blank on how to write the 2nd part of selecting the max(teamKey) when all the counter values are the same.

```
TeamKey Counter
  203     297
  203     761
  203     98
  234     932
```

For Scenario 1: I would pick out TeamKey = 234 as the Counter value is 932 (the max(Counter) value in this data set). But in the 2nd scenario, I need to pick the MAX(TeamKey) when all the counter values are the same. For Example:

```
TeamKey Counter
  203     1
  203     1
  98      1
  981     1
  394     1
```

So, in the above data set, I would select TeamKey = 981 as the counter values are all the same, but TeamKey = 981 is the largest TeamKey value.

In other words, when the counter values are different, pick the TeamKey which has the max Counter value. OR. If the counter values are all the same, then pick the MAX(TeamKey) value.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ace497/1) that I set up with some test data. If you need more information, I'd be more than happy to share details with you. Thank you for taking the time to read the question.

Comment: Can you show what result you want to get? I don't understand the "different teamkey values" because there is only one column and no scenario comparing the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when there is a single max counter you want that row, when it is tied you want the top counter with the highest teamkey? If so this is all you need ;)

```
select top 1 teamkey
       , counter
from testresults
order by counter desc
       , teamkey desc
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will give it a try and mark it as an answer by evening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(Counter) FROM TestResults where exists (select count(distinct teamkey) from TestResults having count(distinct teamkey)>1)
SELECT MAX(Teamkey) FROM TestResults2 where exists (select count(distinct counter) from TestResults2 having count(distinct counter)=1)
```

Comment: I need to combine both the queries into a single piece of code. This is a small part of a larger code set with multiple levels of CTE's. I have figured the part where I want to select the teamKey with the MAX(Counter) when all the counter values are different. I am drawing a blank on the 2nd part. But thank you for your attempt.